# Dagger 2 setup in a multi-module project

Tags: android, gradle, dagger-2, dagger

My project consists of network module, data module and app module.
Network module has a component that only exposes a retrofit service.

```
@Component(modules = [NetworkModule::class])
@NetworkScope
interface NetworkComponent {
  fun apiService(): ApiService
}
```

Data module has a component (not completed yet) that will be exposing Room DAOs. This component has a NetworkComponent dependency.

```
@Component(
  dependencies = [NetworkComponent::class],
  modules = [DataModule::class]
)
@DataScope
interface DataComponent
```

Lastly, I have a app component that has a DataComponent dependency.

```
@Component(
  dependencies = [DataComponent::class],
  modules = [AppModule::class] 
)
@AppScope
interface AppComponent {
  fun application(): Application
}
```

My goal in this setup is that Network modules is only visible in Data module, therefore I have this in build.gradle:

```
implementation project(':network')
```

However, the build fails, as app module (that has data module as dependency) is unable to find Retrofit (which is deliberately not being exposed as I want to keep network stuff in own module).

The build build fine if I change implementation to api, but this exposes network module stuff in app module.
Any ideas?